# Approaching Tricky Combinatorial Proofs - Tough Example

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I'm struggling with finding effective ways to approach questions (especially proofs) that use summations and Taylor Series. I've worked through several simpler examples, but always get stuck once a non-trivial question arises. In particular, I'm hoping to get some help in proving the following statement
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {2i \choose i} \frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}=2(1-\frac{1}{2^{2i}}{2i \choose i})$$

As a hint, it's stated that $ \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{\frac{1}{2}x}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{2i \choose i}\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{x^{i}}{2^{2i}} $ and that it may potentially be necessary to derive the Taylor seires centered at $x=0$ for $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{x} $ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} $

With some help, I've done the following work, but am not sure if I'm either headed in the right direction, or even correct:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {2i \choose i} \frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{2i \choose i} \frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}-\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}{2i \choose i} \frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}=2-\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}{2i \choose i} \frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}$$
From here, I've tried to get to the point of proving the following:
$$2-\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}{2i \choose i} \frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}=2-\frac{2}{2^n}{2n \choose n}$$
$$\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}{2i \choose i} \frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}=\frac{2}{2^n}{2n \choose n} $$
I really don't know where to proceed next, or which direction the proof will continue in. Any additions/corrections would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: to add on another potential solution, would it hold any water to try to write down a recurrence relation, assuming the left side of the first equation to be $ a_n $?

Comment: Consider the general Taylor series expansion $$f(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0} f_kx^k$$ then since $$(1-x)^{-1}=\sum_{l\ge 0}x^l$$ multiplying gives the series of partial sums of $f_k$: $$(1-x)^{-1}f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}f_k\right)x^n$$ You could try calling $f(x)=2(1-\sqrt{1-x})/x$ then multiplying by $(1-x)^{-1}$ to give $2x^{-1}(1-x)^{-1} - 2x^{-1}(1-x)^{-1/2}$ then expanding these as Taylor series about $x=0$ then equate coefficients of $x^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are interested in verifying that

$$S_n = \sum_{q=0}^n {2q\choose q}\frac{1}{q+1}\frac{1}{2^{2q}}
= 2 - \frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n+1\choose n+1}.$$

Now we recognize the Catalan numbers here where

$$C(z) = \sum_{q\ge 0} {2q\choose q}\frac{1}{q+1} z^q
= \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}.$$

We then have from first principles that the sum is given by

$$S_n =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z} C(z/4)\; dz.$$

Now recall  the functional equation (e.g.  from combinatorial species)
of $C(z)$ which is

$$C(z) = 1 + z C(z)^2$$

which means that with $D(z) = C(z/4)$ we obtain

$$D(z) = 1 + z D(z)^2/4.$$

Recall that our integral is

$$S_n =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z} D(z)\; dz.$$

We have that $$z = \frac{4D(z) - 4}{D(z)^2}
= 4\frac{1}{D(z)} - 4\frac{1}{D(z)^2}$$

so in putting $w=D(z)$ we get

$$dz = \left(-4\frac{1}{w^2} + 8\frac{1}{w^3} \right) \; dw$$

which yields for the integral (we have  $D(0) = 1$ as can be seen from
the series)

$$S_n = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma} \frac{w^{2n+2}}{4^{n+1} (w-1)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{1-4/w+4/w^2}
\\ \times w \left(-4\frac{1}{w^2} + 8\frac{1}{w^3} \right) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma} \frac{w^{2n+5}}{4^{n+1} (w-1)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{w^2-4w+4} 
\\ \times \left(-4\frac{1}{w^2} + 8\frac{1}{w^3} \right) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma} \frac{w^{2n+2}}{4^{n+1} (w-1)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(w-2)^2}
\left(-4w + 8\right) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{4^n} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma} \frac{w^{2n+2}}{(w-1)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{1-(w-1)} \; dw.$$

The integral and the scalar in front are

$$\frac{1}{4^n} [(w-1)^{n}] \frac{1}{1-(w-1)} 
\sum_{q=0}^{2n+2} {2n+2\choose q} (w-1)^q
\\ = \frac{1}{4^n} \sum_{q=0}^{n} {2n+2\choose q} 
[(w-1)^{n-q}] \frac{1}{1-(w-1)} 
= \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{q=0}^{n} {2n+2\choose q}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} \left(2^{2n+2} - {2n+2\choose n+1}\right).$$

where the  last step was  by inspection.  We  thus get for  the closed
form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
2 - \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} {2n+2\choose n+1}.}$$

Observe that this is

$$2 - \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} \frac{2n+2}{n+1} {2n+1\choose n}
= 2 - \frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n+1\choose n}
= 2 - \frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n+1\choose n+1}$$

which  is  the  form  presented  in the  introduction.   It  would  be
interesting  to see a  formal power  series only  proof of  this which
would have to have certain  features distinguishing it from the above,
where we used the differential in the integral.

**Remark.** Induction is the simplest here, we get

$$2 - \frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n+1\choose n+1}
+ {2n+2\choose n+1} \frac{1}{n+2}\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}
\\ = 2 - \frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n+1\choose n+1}
+ {2n+3\choose n+2} \frac{1}{2n+3}\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}
\\ = 2 - \frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n+2\choose n+2} \frac{n+2}{2n+2}
+ {2n+3\choose n+2} \frac{1}{2n+3}\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}
\\ = 2 - \frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n+3\choose n+2} 
\frac{n+1}{2n+3} \frac{n+2}{2n+2}
+ {2n+3\choose n+2} \frac{1}{2n+3}\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}.$$

Now

$$4 \frac{n+1}{2n+3} \frac{n+2}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{2n+3}
= 1$$

and we obtain

$$2 - \frac{1}{2^{2n+2}} {2n+3\choose n+2}$$

which is the desired result. (Observe  that $S_1 = 1 + \frac{1}{4} = 2
- \frac{1}{4} {3\choose 2}.$)

Comment: THIS ^ 
Thank you, sir; I had just gone through it inductively before reading your remark, and got the same result.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Hi, Marko! Third approach added :-) (+1).

Comment: Thank you very much. Nice work in your answer. (+1). I did get to present a formal power series coefficient extractor that you might not have seen before.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Yes, I see.  Useful generalisation! :-)  By the way, I've added *[this MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203534)* which might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is  an approach based on the observation that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{2i}}
\end{align*}
is a Cauchy-product which can be interpreted as the coefficient of the product of two (ordinary) generating functions. We recall the generating function of the *[Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)* $C_i=\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}$
\begin{align*}
C(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty C_i x^i=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
It is also convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}
> &=\frac{1}{4^{n-1}}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}4^{n-1-i}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4^{n-1}}[x^{n-1}]\frac{C(x)}{1-4x}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4^{n-1}}[x^{n-1}]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x(1-4x)}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2\cdot4^{n-1}}[x^{n}]\left(\frac{1}{1-4x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2\cdot4^{n-1}}\left(4^n-\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}(-4)^n\right)\tag{6}\\
> &=2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}\right)\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we write the sum as Cauchy-product in the form $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ib_{n-1-i}$.
- In (3) we use the fact that the Cauchy-product is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ of $C(x)$ and the *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* $\frac{1}{1-4x}$.
- In (4) we use the representation (1).
- In (5) we do a small rearrangement to easily derive the coefficients of the series and apply the rule $[x^{p+q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^{-q}A(x)$.
- In (6) we select the coefficient of $x^n$ of the geometric series and the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* with $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}$.
- In (7) we apply the binomial identity 
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{i}=\frac{1}{2^{2i}}\binom{2i}{i}(-1)^i
  \end{align*}
  See e.g. (1.9) in H.W. Goulds *[Binomial Identities, vol. 1](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.1.PDF)*.