# Prove $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}} = 2(1 - \frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n})$

Tags: combinatorics

How can I prove $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}} = 2(1 - \frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n})$ without induction? I think I have to use Taylor series at some point.

Comment: What do you know about Catalan numbers and their interpretation as paths in a grid?

Comment: Is it $\binom{2n}{i}$ in LHS?

Comment: I have no idea about catalan numbers and their interpretation.

Comment: No, it is $\binom{2i}{i}$.

Comment: @J.Griez: in such a case, where did this problem arise? Are you confident in the use of generating functions? I am pretty sure this problem appears in Wilf - *Generatingfunctionology* (https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks for your answer. I am confident with generating functions. Could you please mention in which page Gilf mentioned that?

Comment: @J.Griez: I was wrong, Wilf does not mention such exercise. Maybe it was mentioned by Flajolet in *Analytic Combinatorics*.

Comment: Near identical duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199016/approaching-tricky-combinatorial-proofs-tough-example) asked less than 9 hours previous. The main difference is that there were more hints in the older question and there was no restriction on the method.

Comment: Wouldn't this appear to be a duplicate, see this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199016/)?

Answer (score 1):

[We may notice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) that by setting $C_i=\frac{1}{i+1}\binom{2i}{i}$ and $A_i=\frac{C_i}{4^i}$ we have
$$ f(x) = \sum_{i\geq 0}A_i x^i = 2\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{x}\tag{1} $$
hence
$$ \frac{f(x)}{1-x}=\sum_{i\geq 0}(A_0+\ldots+A_i)x^i = 2 \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{x(1-x)} \tag{2} $$
and the wanted sum is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in the RHS of $(2)$, or the coefficient of $x^n$ in 
$$ \frac{2}{1-x}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x}}\tag{3} $$
whose Taylor series is well-known and leads to
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}A_i = 2-\frac{2}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\tag{4} $$
as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}{2i \choose i}{1 \over i + 1}\,{1 \over 2^{2i}} & =
\bracks{z^{n}}\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}z^{\ell}\bracks{\sum_{i = 0}^{\ell - 1}{2i \choose i}{1 \over i + 1}\,{1 \over 2^{2i}}} =
\bracks{z^{n}}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{2i \choose i}{1 \over i + 1}
\,{1 \over 2^{2i}}\sum_{\ell = i + 1}^{\infty}z^{\ell}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n}}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{2i \choose i}{1 \over i + 1}
\,{1 \over 2^{2i}}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}z^{\ell + i + 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n - 1}}\pars{1 - z}^{-1}
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\
\overbrace{{-1/2 \choose i}\pars{-4}^{i}}^{\ds{2i \choose i}}\
\pars{z \over 4}^{i}\int_{0}^{1}x^{i}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n - 1}}\pars{1 - z}^{-1}
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{-1/2 \choose i}\pars{-zx}^{i}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n - 1}}\pars{1 - z}^{-1}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - zx}^{-1/2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n - 1}}\pars{1 - z}^{-1}\,{2 - 2\pars{1 - z}^{1/2} \over z}
\\[5mm] & =
2\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 - z}^{-1} -
2\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 - z}^{-1/2} =
2 - 2{-1/2 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
2 - 2\,{{2n \choose n} \over \pars{-4}^{n}}\,\pars{-1}^{n} =
\bbx{\ds{2\bracks{1 - {1 \over 2^{2n}}{2n \choose n}}}}
\end{align}

> See a
>   $\ds{{2i \choose i} = {-1/2 \choose i}\pars{-4}^{i}}$ proof in
>   [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1991085/85343).